# i am confused with java Script functions

Tags: javascript, function

so this is some code

```
var name = 'ali';

function say() {
  alert(name);
}
```

so this will alert 'ali' as name function is owned by global object now the following code

```
var oobj  { 
  var name: 'raziq',
  say:function () {
    alert (name);
  }
}

oobj.say();
```

so now the say function is owned by oobj object so the name property should alert 'raziq'
instead of 'ali'. by the way i know the use of this keyword

my question is what will be alerted and y ?

Comment: oops sorry about the typos

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the second example contains invalid syntax. also you should avoid variables which have the same name as named functions in the same scope.

Comment: so the name property should alert 'raziq' instead of 'ali'.

Comment: in oobj object because function belongs to oobj

Comment: I provided an answer to make what you posted work, but I think I am still a little confused at what you are asking

Comment: If you are saying that it is alerting 'ali' instead of 'raziq', then yes. That is the outcome. name is a global variable which you assigned to 'ali'. oobj.name is 'raziq'. If you want oobj.say() to alert 'raziq' change the say function to alert `this.name` instead of name

Comment: You still have `var name: 'raziq',`. It should just be `name: 'raziq',`

Comment: "what will be alerted and y". Take my advise, this is not facebook, please dont write like a 12 year old girl.

Answer (score 8):

---Update---

Basically, one is a variable and one is a property. You access them two different ways

In your question, you declare a variable `name` and a function. at any point, if you do not specifically redefine `name` then it will always be that value.

In your case, you think you are redefining `name` when you do

```
var oobj = {
    name: 'raziq'
```

but you aren't. You are declaring a property of the oobj object. i.e. if i try to alert name from outside the object, it will look  to find a variable declaration of name and it will find the global variable that you set to 'ali'. In order to get to `property` name, you have to tell it the "path" to find it. The path is `oobj.name`

You are inside an object, so you don;t use `var =` and `;`. You use a comma `,` and you just do `say: function() {`

```
var oobj = {
    name: 'raziq',
    say: function () {
        alert(this.name);
    }
}
oobj.say();
```

Comment: Updated to try and explain. Does that help?

Comment: yea to some extend but my question is when i alert the name property in oobj object it should alert 'raziq' because i am inside the object and the function also belongs to object

Comment: In your post you aren't alerting a property. You are telling it to alert the variable name. Which is set to 'ali'. The property has to be accessed by using either `oobj.name` outside the object OR `this.name` inside the object. If you change it to what I have in my code example, it will do what you want because I tell it to alert the name property instead of the name variable

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff has already posted the right answer, I just wanted to point out, that even the first example is not working as intended. The inner `alert` will show you the `name` function.

So this:

```
function name() {
  alert(name);
}

name()
```

Will alert the message:

```
function name() {
  alert(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for this

```
var oobj = { 
    name : 'raziq',
    say : function (){
            alert (oobj.name);
        }
}

oobj.say();
```

See an [updated fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/basillicum/5uj2b/) and an [extended fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/basillicum/5uj2b/3/).

Comment: yes but why should we indicate the oobj.name when the function is owned by that object

Comment: because `name` is a parameter of `oobj` object. You can also use `this.name` instead of `oobj.name`

Comment: when it is a part of oobj object why should we care about "this" and the name of the oobj any way

Comment: Here is something (very) useful to know in this case http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/ (Using scope & closures in javascript)